# Vga screen goes black for 2 seconds then on then off etc

Tags: screen

I am having issues with my PI3 and my crt vga arcade monitor.

The image will appear for 2 seconds then disappear and this is basically a constant loop.

I have changed different resolutions but still no luck and I have also plugged it in to my LCD and it works fine, no problems what so ever.

Any suggestions or has any one had this issue before. Before the PI3 I was using a game elf which displayed 800x600 53hz /31khzwith no problems at